# Reading a file using VBScript on a terminal server

Tags: vba, outlook, terminal-services

Raised this as a new post as requested.

This script does exactly what I want on a local PC: adds a text file, puts it in a text box for confirmation, once confirmed adds the text to the subject of the email. But when the same script is run a terminal server it cannot find the file. Any idea why it cannot see the file and why this would not work on a terminal server?

As I said all local installs of Outlook work fine, it can find the `email.txt` file, but on a terminal server it does not. I have confirmed that the file is in the location.

```
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
    Dim fso, f
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\temp\email.txt")
    ReadAllTextFile = f.ReadAll
End Function

Public Sub UpdateSubject()
    Dim SaveCode As String
    Dim KeyWord As String
    Dim objItem As MailItem

    KeyWord = "ABD"

    SaveCode = InputBox("Please enter filecode in the format nnn/nnn", "VisualFiles Auto Save", ReadAllTextFile)
    MsgBox SaveCode
    Set objItem = GetCurrentItem()
    objItem.Subject = "[" + KeyWord + "=" + SaveCode + "] " + objItem.Subject
End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application

    Set objApp = Application
    On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
    Set objApp = Nothing
End Function
```

If I message out the location like Below it gives me the correct location, for example `C:\users\bobby\temp\email.txt`.

```
MsgBox (Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\temp\email.txt")
```

Comment: Your code is a) incomplete and b) invalid VBScript, so it's clearly not possible that the code (as a VBScript) would have run successfully anywhere. Did you perhaps mean VBA? Is Outlook installed on the terminal server?

Comment: You are correct young man It is VBA not VBS, sheez (Bangs head on desk) i am really new to this VBS c# VBA coding, i am a visual files developer not a programmer but been asked to see if i can get this to work. yes outlook is installed and the macro and button work fine but just does not read the file

Comment: Your code is still incomplete, it starts in the middle of a function. However, are you sure the file `Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\temp\email.txt"` exists? The windows-specific `temp` folder is (usually) not directly in the UserProfile folder (check `environ("Temp")`, so this must be manually created.

Comment: Function ReadAllTextFile()
   Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\temp\email.txt")
   ReadAllTextFile = f.ReadAll
   
End Function

Comment: the user environ is c:\users\%username% that is the result adding to that \temp\email.txt creates the correct file location. the file location exists the file exists messaging out the file location is correct is correct same script works perfectly fine on a local install

Answer (score 0):

Ok news for you all the reason the VBA code would not work on the Terminal server was that the following DLL was not installed on the terminal

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLVBS.DLL

To fix it was as simple as copy from a working PC to the same place on the terminal server. restart the server. So the script works fine